# Dependency Injection using together

Tags: model-view-controller, dependency-injection, structuremap, autofac

I have an mvc project. I use Autofac In Entity Access Layer and StructureMap in Membership provider.

Can I use Autofac and structuremap together in single mvc project?

Thnx

Comment: You can, but you should avoid at all cost. This can cause issues down the track, such as maintainability issues, confusions (not knowing which DI to use etc). Also ASP.NET MVC3, for instance you can can associate your DI framework with MVC and you can only associate a single DI framework.

Comment: @Raj "you can only associate a single DI framework." It's not right, you can associate only a single IDependencyResolver implementation, which could contain anything you want.

Comment: I have to 2 DI, because I must use memflex membership for authentication and repository pattern for Entity Access Layer that use Autofac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you are using ASP.NET MVC in your project. Then, you just need to implement ASP.NET MVC IDependencyResolver interface which contains only two methods and looks like:

```
public interface IDependencyResolver
{
    object GetService(Type serviceType);
    IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType);
}
```

Your implementation should take two parameters into its constructor: Autofac dependency resolver and StructureMap dependency resolver. It could look like this:

```
public class CombinedDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
{
    private readonly AutofacDependencyResolver _autofacDependencyResolver;
    private readonly StructureMapDependencyResolver _structureMapDependencyResolver;

    public CombinedDependencyResolver(AutofacDependencyResolver autofacDependencyResolver, StructureMapDependencyResolver structureMapDependencyResolver)
    {
        _autofacDependencyResolver = autofacDependencyResolver;
        _structureMapDependencyResolver = structureMapDependencyResolver;
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        // your logic here
        _structureMapDependencyResolver.GetService(serviceType);
        _autofacDependencyResolver.GetService(serviceType);
        return new object();
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        // your logic here
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then implement IDependencyResolver's methods according to your logic and resolve dependencies either from AutofacDependencyResolver or StructureMapDependencyResolver.